# Creating an API multi thread in R

Tags: r, api, plumber

I'm thinking about creating an API with Rscript doing all my stuff.

But, we know that R is single-thread, and plumber also is.

Someone know a way to create an API multi thread in R? I dont think that an single-thread can help me in my case, I may have many users using my model in prod, then im afraid to use plumber.

I already see people saying about using RServer and Java to create an API multi thread. (but i dont know how do this).

Any suggestion, or links about this discussion is welcome.

Thank you all!

Comment: Have a look at doParallel and foreach...

Comment: Why do you think it is single threaded? Most R libraries that take advantage of multithread like data.table and xgboost will be multithreaded even when used with plumber. Plumber uses promises so you should not have any problem sending in concurrent request to the API.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay i saw in this discussion about plumber be single thread https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/170

Comment: Check the top item in the changelog, https://www.rplumber.io/news/index.html

Comment: @BrunoTremblay omfg, hell yeah. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just to document things that are possible to other people that may have the same question, and dont know how do this, I will put here some links that i found that can be helpful.

I dont test any idea yet to say which one is faster, or cheaper, or optimized...

But, what i found is:

1. You can use https://restrserve.org/ that is an alternative to plumber, even when plumber was just single-thread, restrserve already was helpful to create APIs multi-thead.
2. 8 days ago, plumber release the version 1.0.0, that can support APIs multi-thread. Link to release: https://www.rplumber.io/news/index.html#plumber-router
3. Even in the past, without plumber v1.0.0, or if you dont want use the RestRserve, you could create an API single-thread with the plumber (in the past), use the Docker to Build your API and then use Kubernetes to manage the requests, creating "copys" of your API, and then the Kubernetes manage the requests, choosing the copy_API that will be used.

An talk at RSTUDIO::CONF2020 about an model that has 1.000.000 acces per day, with an R API: https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2020/we-re-hitting-r-a-million-times-a-day-so-we-made-a-talk-about-it/